# R efficient way to sort a Matrix by row

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix "multiOrderPairsFlat" of 2m+ rows and 2 columns where each cell contains a SKU description (e.g. "Pipe2mSteel" or "Bushing1inS") and would like to sort every row alphabetically, so that in every row, e.g. "Bushings1inS" is in the first column and "Pipe2mSteel" in the second.

However, if I run:

```
for (i in 1:length(multiOrderPairsFlat)){
  multiOrderPairsFlat[i,] <- sort(multiOrderPairsFlat[i,])
}
```

It takes forever and I doubt this is the quickest way of dealing with this problem. Do you have any advice on how to solve this more efficiently, e.g. by vectorizing the operation?

Thanks for helping out;)
Best
seulberg1

Comment: Side note: Maybe one can add an answer describing how this could this be achieved using `Rcpp`?  Sth like `require(Rcpp);cppFunction('CharacterMatrix sortmat( CharacterMatrix x ){ int nr = x.nrow(); for(int r = 0; r < nr; r++){ ... }; return x}')`. I'd be interested...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to use `pmin/pmax` after converting to `data.frame` (as there are only two columns)

```
 system.time({
 df1 <- as.data.frame(multiOrderPairsFlat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  res <- data.frame(First = do.call(pmin, df1), Second = do.call(pmax, df1))

 })
 #    user  system elapsed 
 #  0.49    0.02    0.50 

system.time({
  for (i in 1:nrow(multiOrderPairsFlat)){
    multiOrderPairsFlat[i,] <- sort(multiOrderPairsFlat[i,])
  }
 })

#  user  system elapsed 
#  11.99    0.00   12.00 

all.equal(as.matrix(res), multiOrderPairsFlat, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Checking the memory allocation

```
library(profvis)

profvis({
 df1 <- as.data.frame(multiOrderPairsFlat, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 res <- data.frame(First = do.call(pmin, df1), Second = do.call(pmax, df1))

  })

#3.3 MB
profvis({
 for (i in 1:nrow(multiOrderPairsFlat)){
  multiOrderPairsFlat[i,] <- sort(multiOrderPairsFlat[i,])
  }
})

#12.8 MB
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
multiOrderPairsFlat <- cbind(sample(c("Pipe2mSteel" , "Bushing1inS"), 1e6, replace=TRUE),
    sample(c("Pipe2mSteel" , "Bushing1inS"), 1e6, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: That did indead speed it up by 2x% :) Thank you.